# How to select product that have the maximum price of each category?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

The below is my table that has the item such as:

```
ProductId       ProductName Category        Price
      1            Tiger      Beer          $12.00
      2             ABC       Beer          $13.99
      3            Anchor     Beer          $9.00
      4            Apolo      Wine          $10.88
      5           Randonal    Wine          $18.90
      6            Wisky      Wine          $30.19
      7             Coca     Beverage       $2.00
      8            Sting     Beverage       $5.00
      9             Spy      Beverage       $4.00
     10           Angkor      Beer          $12.88
```

And I suppose that I have only three `category` in this table (I can have a lot of `category` in this table). And I want to show the maximum product's price of each `category` in this table.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? mysql? db2? mssql?

Comment: @John Woo - `sql` tag means `ansi sql`

Comment: @Grisha In which case, the OP is using an entirely theoretical database.

Comment: @kimleng since you are using MSSQL, why not use window functions? see the demonstration below.

Comment: @podiluska it could be for example in academic course

Comment: @Grisha which is what "theoretical" means.

Comment: @podiluska - In my comment to John Woo, I meant that it might be theoretical db and not "real" (mysql/db2/mssql...) What's wrong ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this one if you want to get the whole row,

(*supports most RDBMS*)

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tbProduct a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Category, MAX(Price) maxPrice
            FROM tbProduct
            GROUP BY Category
        ) b ON a.category = b.category AND
                a.price = b.maxPrice
```

If you are using `MSSQL 2008+`

```
WITH allProducts AS
(
SELECT  ProductId,ProductName,Category,Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY Price DESC) ROW_NUM
FROM tbProduct
)
SELECT ProductId,ProductName,Category,Price
FROM allProducts
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

or

```
SELECT ProductId,ProductName,Category,Price
FROM    
(
SELECT  ProductId,ProductName,Category,Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY Price DESC) ROW_NUM
FROM tbProduct
) allProducts
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bbc9/1)

Comment: how clever you are. Could I know you, sir?

Comment: @kimleng off topic, you can add me on facebook :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT   Category,max(Price) as Price
FROM     tbProduct
GROUP BY Category
```

If you want to retrieve other fields also along with the category name then :

```
select * 
from  tbProduct T
join   (
         select Category,max(Price) as Price
         from tbProduct
         group by Category)a
on     T.Category=a.Category
and    T.Price=a.Price
```

Comment: @kimleng: Please try the second query in my answer

Comment: Hello sir. It is Syntax Error in From Clause. Can you write me the complete statement. My table name is tbProduct. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16533/discussion-between-joe-g-joseph-and-kimleng)

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from
(Select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by category order by price desc) rn 
        from products) v
where rn=1
```

Comment: Please add detail and explanation.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Like every other answer, you mean?

Comment: "Just because Jimmy jumps off the roof, doesn't mean you have to jump as well", or, "two wrongs don't make a right".

Comment: @JohnSaunders So why pick on this answer?

Comment: Because it showed up on the "Review" tab. I didn't downvote, though. I just suggest you add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT Category, MAX(Price)
FROM Products
GROUP BY Category
```

This groups the table by each category and uses the `MAX` aggregate function to get the highest price per each.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing so where MAX is treated as analytical function (Available since SQL Server 2005)

```
    Declare @t table(ProductId  int identity, ProductName varchar(100), Category varchar(20), Price numeric(10,2))
    Insert Into @t Select 'Tiger','Beer',12.00
    Insert Into @t Select 'ABC','Beer',13.99
    Insert Into @t Select 'Anchor','Beer',9.00
    Insert Into @t Select 'Apolo','Wine',10.88
    Insert Into @t Select 'Randonal','Wine',18.90
    Insert Into @t Select 'Wisky','Wine',30.19
    Insert Into @t Select 'Coca','Beverage',2.00
    Insert Into @t Select 'Sting','Beverage',5.00
    Insert Into @t Select 'Spy','Beverage',4.00
    Insert Into @t Select 'Angkor','Beer',12.88

SELECT ProductId,ProductName,Category,Price
FROM(
        SELECT
            ProductId
            ,ProductName
            ,Category
            ,Price
            ,CASE WHEN Price =  MAX(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) THEN 'Take' ELSE 'Leave' END AS PickUp   

        FROM @t

        )X  WHERE PickUp = 'Take' ORDER BY 1
```

**Result**

```
ProductId   ProductName Category    Price
2           ABC         Beer            13.99
6           Wisky       Wine            30.19
8           Sting       Beverage        5.00
```

Comment: Check your results again - Coca costs 2, not 5, Tiger 12, not 13.99. You are selecting random rows because you order by the same value.

Comment: Thanks for that.I completely overlooked. Fixed the bug

Comment: @NiladriBiswas What if after this I need the price in order keeping rest or condition as same. Let's say in this case Category Wine with Wisky as ProductName has highest price  so this has to come first in order then Beer ABC and then Beverage Sting

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   Category,max(Price) as ProdPrice
FROM     tbProduct
GROUP BY Category
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT TOP(7)*,
             Row_number()
               OVER (
                 partition BY category
                 ORDER BY price DESC) rn
FROM   products
ORDER  BY price DESC
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question ([sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03923/4) using base from John Woo's answer). Perhaps add text describing how it improves on previous answers (and why you selected `TOP(7)` which seems to result in an incomplete answer e.g. it excludes "Beverage").

Comment: This dont looks an answer to question. It might requires the max and group by selection